# How to link aspx form to content type's new item adding?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, custom-form, aspx, module

I have created one content type and list along with module (as aspx) page in visual studio , Now when I click on new item of list then i can open the newly created form but I want something like, when I select content type then it should open some other aspx page
what should i do? please guide

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7103/sp2010-modal-dialog-for-content-type-new-form?rq=1

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46370/content-types-new-item?rq=1


go through this 2 links this may help you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473210%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on MSDN.
I think FormUrls can be of help in your case.

> This schema enables you to specify client-side redirects to different Display, Edit, and New form pages for items of this content type.

Comment: thanks for solution but this will only works when sharepoint online, if I am not wrong

Comment: No, this is *also* available in SharePoint Online, not *only*

Comment: but I am not working sharepoint Online ! I have to do this for onprimises

Comment: what did I just say? This will work either in SharePoint on premises and SharePoint Online.

Comment: actually want to ask you that does it work on sharepoint on premises ? beacuase I have tried this solution and also the link of MSDN gives by you , there is mention that it will work on sharepoint online

Comment: Good Lord, I don't know how I could say it differently. YES, **this works on sharepoint on premises**.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it through Javascript, adding it to the page when a user clicks on the specified contentype than it would load the aspx page.

another way would be to load the newform.aspx witin sharepoint designer and ammending it that way through code and adding an event to its control to trigger a new page or redirect!

i dont think you could use an item added event or adding as that is for the list as a whole rather than idividual item to load aspx.

Comment: thanks for solution but I am little confused with that. In this case I have to use visual studio only
and I have not written any server side code for adding item for that I am going to use SPServices 
BUt My Question is I have created a page which will render when I click on new item in list but problem comes when there is multiple content type for list

Comment: for that instance I have to create a form for seperate content type.How should I proced?